# What I have to do for logging error by passbook web service reference

Tags: logging, ios6, error-logging, passbook

in Logging Errors, device sends POST request to webServiceURL/version/log, so what server have to do in this point ?

Comment: Just store the errors that the devices send back - you should review the errors regularly and address any problems that they show.  When debugging a new application they can be helpful.

Comment: how to store those errors ? My code doesn't work: if (strtoupper($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']) === "POST" && $request[3]==='log'){
 error_log("Logs: " .$logs, 0);
 response200();
}

Comment: The data is sent as JSON - use the same code that you use to get the pushToken then write the JSON object to the log.

Comment: I just response 200 in this method, and it works !

Comment: Thank you PassKit! but I don't know how to write JSON object to log !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To log the output to the PHP log you can use something like:

```
$log_items = json_decode(@file_get_contents('php://input'))->logs;
foreach($log_items as $key => $log_message)
    error_log("Passbook Error Log: " . $log_message, 0);
```

Comment: Your comment describes a log message, you can see it in your PHP error log.  You are getting this warning because your web service responded to the "Get Latest Version of a Pass" method with a .pkpass bundle that was exactly the same as the .pkpass bundle already installed.  To avoid this message, if the pass has not changed, you need to respond to the get serials method with a `204` response and the get latest version method with a `304` response.

Comment: I use max(updateTag) for finding new latest version of pass; but I still get : Apr  9 11:07:28 CamMobs-iPod4 passd[3102] <Warning>: Get serial #s task (for device 7933e8415e97e2fc19cd905791b8fd54, pass type pass.cam-mob.passbookpasstest, last updated 1365479301; with web service url http://192.168.1.202:8888/passesWebserver/) encountered error: Server response was malformed (Array for key serialNumbers in response dictionary must contain objects of type NSString. Found object of type NSNull.)

Comment: You need to check if the updateTag value of the record you retrieve is greater than the passesUpdatedSince tag that you receive.  If not, then send `204`, if yes then send the serials JSON and a new lastUpdated tag.

Comment: but updateTag is timestamp and passesUpdatedSince tage is string , how to compare them ?

Comment: Since you control both, why not just use a unix timestamp.  If not use PHP's [strtotime](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php) function to convert them both to timestamps.

Comment: when I use:  $updateTag = array($row['max(updateTag)']);
I see in php_error.log: [09-Apr-2013 08:45:31 Europe/Berlin] PHP Notice:  Array to string conversion in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/passesWebserver/index.php on line 97

Comment: `$updateTag = array($row['max(updateTag)'])` is not valid PHP

Comment: I use it as I want the lastest updateTag. Above it, there is :  $querySelect = mysql_query("select serialNo, passTypeID, authenticationToken, max(updateTag) from digiCardPass");
  
 $row = mysql_fetch_array($querySelect);
 
 $serialsArray = array($row['serialNo']);

Comment: `mysql_query("SELECT serialNo, passTypeID, authenticationToken, MAX(updateTag) AS updateTag from digiCardPass");`  then use `$updateTag = $row['updateTag'];`